# How to recover my files and personal data a phone who doesn't boot?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, boot, data-recovery

My Galaxy S II runs under Android 4.12 and it is stuck on the boot screen. How can I recover my files and personal data on the phone ?

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question and add some more details? Especially useful hints include 1) whether you still can boot into recovery-mode, 2) whether you have a custom recovery installed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Is the Phone rooted and is USB-Debugging enabled?

If yes, you could probably boot into recovery and try recovering the files via ADB.

[How to copy selected files from Android with adb pull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8650407/how-to-copy-selected-files-from-android-with-adb-pull) shows you how to work with ADB to recover your Files ;)

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can recover files and folders over the device which isn't booting up I would say first of all fix the booting problem up and then you can take the help of various recovery apps and software available to restore the deleted files and folder. I am know you can't recover 100% of them out but I would say to some extent you may get most out of it !

Comment: As [Anders' answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/85300/16575) shows, that's not fully true. OP is just stating the device is not booting up *normally* – so there still might be options via recovery-mode.